# C# tabPage

Tags: c#, winforms

Интересует следующая вещь: Можно ли каким то образом добавить в заголовок tabPage кнопку:
[image]

и каким образом ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотри тут http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20050/FireFox-like-Tab-Control